# Retrieve web-element parent attributes and values

Tags: html

Retrieve web-element parent attributes and values and preceding label element attributes and values.

We are using **JSoup** to scrape html page.

Comment: show what you've done by the way of some code

Comment: Without code snippet only lord can help you....